# XmlHttpRequest token missing from reply

Tags: javascript, jwt

I have the following JavaScript code sending login credentials to a REST API:

```
function login() {
    let myUsername = document.getElementById('username').value;
    let myPassword = document.getElementById('password').value;
    //window.alert("Login was clicked with" + myUsername + " " + myPassword);

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/planesserver/login/");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/fhir+json");
    const body = JSON.stringify({
       "username": myUsername,
       "password": myPassword
    });
    xhr.onload = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
         console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
         //console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader("Authorization"));
         console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders
         ());
    } else {
        console.log(`Error: ${xhr.status}`);
    }
  };
   xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xhr.readyState === xhr.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
       const token = xhr.getResponseHeader("Authorization");
       console.log(`token : ${token}`);
      }
   }
   xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
   xhr.send(body);    
}
```

The reply to the request should include an "Authorization" key in header which has as value a JWT token. In Postman it works beautifully. But with this JavaScript I am not receiving this header. In fact I am only receiving this:

```
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
expires: 0
pragma: no-cache
```

Has anyone an idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `Authorization` makes no sense as a *response*. It's always a request header. That said, if the server you're working with really made that mistake, I wouldn't be surprised browsers filter those security headers out by default anyway. If you see the header in the network tab, but you can't read the header it means the browser probably filtered it for security reasons.